# SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position Y

Tags: json, node.js, pm2

So I have a function that its sole purpose is to parse JSON's that get dynamically generated but not by my program. Sometimes those JSON's might not meet the proper syntax for a variety of reasons raging from network lag to simply broken json structures. To parse a JSON I use

`try { JSON.parse(LARGE_JSON) } catch(e) { .. log the error }`

For some reason now, after many parses it seems like my nodejs is leaking and finally encoutering an syntax error

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token X in JSON at position 19837
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Pipe.channel.onread (internal/child_process.js:470:28)
```

That error crashes the whole process with it, even though I am using try catch. So I really don't understand how to tackle neither the memory leak nor the crashing process, what might the issue be?

Comment: Are you sure the error message is from this line of code, and not from some other place in your program where you might be parsing JSON?

Comment: In any place I am parsing a JSON in my code I do it inside a try catch, except from some lines, where I have a big try catch that I parse two JSON's.

Comment: Is there any way to log more error information perhaps when the error occurs?

Comment: Are you using promises? Keep in mind promises won't throw, instead you have to use the .catch method. Also consider using process.on('uncaughtException and process.on('unhandledRejection